# How can I get a selector to do a partial lookup on any field in the list

Tags: acumatica

I have a selector that is selecting cases among several other fields, as follows:

```
        [PXSelector(typeof(Search2<CRCase.caseCD,
                               InnerJoin<PMProject,
                                    On<CRCase.customerID, Equal<PMProject.customerID>>>,
                        Where<PMProject.contractID, Equal<Current<EPTimecardDetail.projectID>>>,
                        OrderBy<Desc<CRCase.caseCD>>>),
        typeof(CRCase.caseCD),
        typeof(CRCase.subject),
        typeof(CRCase.createdDateTime), 
        typeof(CRCase.caseClassID), 
        typeof(CRCase.status), 
        typeof(CRCase.contactID),
        typeof(CRCase.ownerID))]
```

[image]

When the selector is open, the search bar will only search on the first field - the CaseCD.  If I type part of the Subject field text, I want it to show, as in other lookups, the entries that have that snippet of text in them.  i.e., if I know part of the Subject field, I want it to filter or show entries filtered on that bit of text I enter.

Is there a setting in the PXSelector attribute that allows this, or would it be on the aspx page for the Selector?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the past (unless there is something new) we set the FastFilterFields in the page.

Ex from project entry on contract cd (page PM301000):

```
<px:PXSegmentMask ID="edContractCD" runat="server" DataField="ContractCD" DataSourceID="ds" AutoRefresh="True">
                <GridProperties FastFilterFields="Description, CustomerID, CustomerID_Customer_acctName" />
            </px:PXSegmentMask>
```

Each field listed in FastFilterFields will be searchable in the selector.

Use of FastFilterFields will apply to `PXSegmentMask` or `PXSelector`.

Another example showing selector:

```
<px:PXSelector ID="edReceiptNbr" runat="server" DataField="ReceiptNbr" AutoRefresh="true">
                <GridProperties FastFilterFields="InvoiceNbr, VendorID, VendorID_Vendor_acctName">
                </GridProperties>
            </px:PXSelector>
```

Comment: What if I have a PXSelector and not a PXSegmentMask?  I tried this in a PXSelector tag and it didn't do it.

Comment: same result for each. SegmentMask and Selector perform the same with the search window